# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras'. Inspite of having latest tensorflow version installed

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, modulenotfounderror

I have installed Tensorflow (version 2.12.0) yet i keep getting
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras'
I was trying to use it as such :

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
```

and i'm getting

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "D:\Edukan\final_aug\aug.py", line 1, in <module>
> from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras'

I have installed Tensorflow already and can confirm as well :

```
pip show tensorflow
```

and gives an correct output regarding the info of Tensorflow 2.12.0 (as seen in image)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZboV.png)

I have tried Uninstalling and reinstalling Tensorflow and no luck there.

What could be the possible reason of this ?
I have a docker container where I am able to run Tensorflow
Other than that i was also experimenting with install CUDA along with Tensorflow to use my local GPU(and I have failed so using a docker container)
maybe something have might gone wrong there ?

Comment: What is the output of `pip --version` and  `python --version`? You may have different runtimes and have `python3` and `python` being different.

Comment: Ignore my answer below as I misunderstood your problem. Can you please provide more information? like your `kears` and `python` versions?

Comment: pip 23.1.2 , Python 3.9.7, Keras 2.12.0 , Tensorflow 2.12.0